# Error 401 during inviting people MS Azure Dev/Ops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I would like to invite my friends to the project in the MS Azure Dev/Ops, but when they try to accept the email invitation, they see “error 401 - you don’t have permission to this website”. How to solve this problem? I have free account.

Answer (score 1):

> Error 401 during inviting people MS Azure Dev/Ops

Please suggest your friends to log in the invitation link in private/Incognito mode with browser:

[image]

If he still can not access, please double check if he is added to your organization, you could try to delete he and re-add to check if it works.

**Update:**

Try to visit this site:

[https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=en-US&campaign=o~msft~old~vsts~profile](https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=en-US&campaign=o%7Emsft%7Eold%7Evsts%7Eprofile)

and check the directory to find the organization:

[image]

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: @Michal, You need provide more info about this issue, otherwise, no one knows what your specific problem is. You need tell us if this user in your Users list of your organization and how about the result delete he and re-add and visit this site: https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=en-US&campaign=o~msft~old~vsts~profile to check if he in the correct directory.

Comment: @Michal, Check my update answer to switch different directory to check if the organization exists.

Comment: This user is on the organization list, but I can see, that he didn't log in to it. I haven't any directories(and this user too), because this is a new account. When I remove and add the user to the organization it doesn't help - his invitation link isn't working. He can see, that he hasn't permission to access this page.

Comment: If you have confirmed the above information and cannot solve your problem, then I think your problem should be related to the account itself, there may be a conflict or other account, which requires the account and org name to query the background data. But since SO is an public forum, it is not recommended for you to do so. In addition, I saw that you also submitted the same question on Developer Community. I suggest you follow up on this issue on Developer Community.

Comment: @Michal, I have check your account in the backend, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-401-during-inviting-people-MS-Azur/1526146 and confirm that the account is indeed abnormal. The engineer on the Developer Community will report your problem to the product team and request to correct the information from the background. During this period, the communication may take a little time. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: So I'm waiting :)